# ajax with php data flicker update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I'm working on this site that needs to retrieve updated results from a mysql database which I did through a php script that echos the output in html.

I just started getting into ajax and would appreciate some help as to why this flickers the entire page when the update is being done to the specific div.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Ajax(){
        var xmlHttp;
        try{    
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        }
        catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
            }
            catch (e){
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e){
                    alert("No AJAX!?");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
                document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
                setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
            }
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET","http://xxxxxx.com/updatePlayerList.php",true);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    window.onload=function(){
        setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div id="ReloadThis"></div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The flicker is caused because you write the entire div each time. Why don't you just append or prepend the data to the div instead....

The advantage is low data exchange and controlled output.

Also no need for writing setTimeout after every calls, better use setInterval which will update the div on each interval.

You can append using

```
 $("#ReloadThis").append(strHtml); // strHtml is the html in string format to be appended
```

and prepend using

```
$("#ReloadThis").prepend(strHtml); // strHtml is the html in string format to be prepended
```